# Fetch Location using "location 4.4.0" not working on iOS 16 simulator and device. uncaught error occurred

Tags: flutter, dart, location

i am using location: ^4.2.0 in flutter. This version not supported with ios version 16.

```
final Location location = Location();

if (!await location.serviceEnabled()) {
  if (!await location.requestService()) throw 'GPS service is disabled';
  print("GPS service is disabled");
}
if (await location.hasPermission() == PermissionStatus.denied) {
  if (await location.requestPermission() != PermissionStatus.granted)
    throw 'No GPS permissions';
  print("No GPS permissions");
}
final LocationData data = await location.getLocation();
print("${data.latitude}, ${data.longitude}");
```

Comment: Try to use geolocator package instead. Most probably the location package does not support IOS 16 yet.

Comment: Maybe its a stimulator issue. Visit  https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/issues/775

Answer (score 1):

Use geolocator package. location: ^4.2.0 package is not supporting iOS 16 yet.

Use this: https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

```
geolocator: ^9.0.2
```

Geolocator package supports ios 16.

Comment: yes, still location having issue with ios but geolocator is working fine